# WinForm Override .ShowDialog() in multiple projects

Tags: c#, winforms, overloading

I’m currently working on a big Solution, containing multiple Projects.

on many Forms I used `form.ShowDialog();` or `from.Show();`
*(name of form instead of form)*

I made a loading screen using  speared threads.

so I need to Overload every `form.Show()` and `form.ShowDialog()` to implement this new function.

Iv searched Google for a couple of hours, but I cannot find anything useful.
and I tried different  thins myself. 
But cant figure this out.

Is there a way to overload every form  `Show()` and `ShowDialog()` in a Solution?

Comment: What do you want to overload your `ShowDialog` and `Show`?

Comment: Before the `Show` i want to display a load screen in a second thread

Comment: OK, I understand what you want, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to make your forms derive from a custom base class that overrides the default functionality of `Show()` and `ShowDialog()`.  This would mean that you would need to find any form you use for either of the two methods and implement this functionality. e.g.

Create a custom class that implements form:

```
public class CustomForm : Form
{
    public DialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Derive from that form, e.g.

```
public partial class Form2 : CustomForm
{

}
```

Call it,

```
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: this will still call base method if called from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` type

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You are correct in that fact -- that's why my solution is to derive from a custom base type.

Comment: Deriving from custom type also won't help when casted to `Form` type and called `ShowDialog` right? better to mention in your answer is my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Using some esoteric Win32 calls, it might be possible to hook these methods. However, you'd be going well outside the realm of .NET to do so, and the solution would be more complex than it would be worth. I recommend one of two things:

1. Create a base class that derives from `Form`. The new base class will contain new declarations for the `Show` and `ShowDialog` methods (using the `new` keyword to hide the underlying `Form` members). Add your new logic to that and call the original `Form.Show`/`Form.ShowDialog` when appropriate. Have every form in your application derive from your new base class.
2. Add a static utility method (or extension method) that does the same stuff you would have put in the base class above.

Answer (score 0):

Have every form in your solution inherit from a custom class that you write that then inherits from Form.  If you override .Show and .ShowDialog in this "middle" class it will apply to all the forms that sub-class it.  This will still require you to touch every form file in your solution, but this is the proper way to implement common code across many forms.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your cs file

```
using ext;

namespace ext
{
    public static class extensions
    {
        public static DialogResult ShowDialog(this Form form, string title)
        {
            DialogResult ret;


            form.Text = title;

            ret = form.ShowDialog();

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

This will overload all form ShowDialog() functions to take in and set the form title when showing the dialog.

```
private void form(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowDialog("My new title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the cleanest solution for you. I understand that there are many forms in your project which are not convenient to re-organize (such as by letting them inherit from the same form class and override `Show` and `ShowDialog` in that class). This solution requires you to have access only to the `Handle` of the form you want to `hook` or `insert` code to execute before showing that form:

```
public class FormWndProc : NativeWindow {
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
      if(m.Msg == 0x18&&m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero)//WM_SHOWWINDOW = 0x18
      {
         //your code here
         //you can use m.HWnd to get the Handle of the form
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
}
//use the class
//suppose you want to execute the code before showing the form1, form2, form3
new FormWndProc().AssignHandle(form1.Handle);
new FormWndProc().AssignHandle(form2.Handle);
new FormWndProc().AssignHandle(form3.Handle);
//you can save the instance of FormWndProc to call the ReleaseHandle() method later if you don't want to insert code before showing the form.
```

If you have access to your forms, I mean you can override directly the method `WndProc`, you can do something like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
  ///....
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
      if(m.Msg == 0x18&&m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero)//WM_SHOWWINDOW = 0x18
      {
         //your code here
         //you can use m.HWnd to get the Handle of the form
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
//This way you don't need the class FormWndProc as defined above.
```